# Script for rsyncing to cloud drive (webdav)

Tags: backup, cloud, rsync

How could I make a script to sync all my files from a local server to a cloud space? This is intended to work as **backup**.

1. Problem: Check if the cloud drive is connected, if not, connect it. As it's webdav only, I constantly ran into issues with davfs2. When the connection is closed unexpectedly, the folder remained mounted, but inaccessible, causing rsync to hang and also making it impossible to remount it.
2. Problem: I want to limit transfer speed so my line isn't totally blocked all the time. I'm talking about a lot of data, that may take weeks to upload initially.
3. Problem: Keep it in sync - I'm clueless about what rsync does out-of-the-box and what not, but sure enough I only want to copy changed & new files, overwrite changed files without asking and most importantly, resume the transfer of part uploads. EDIT: For that part the following command should probably do:

   ```
   rsync -a -u -z -P  /source/ /target/ --bwlimit=1000 --append-verify
   ```

However, another problem arose..

4. Problem: The hoster only supports file size up to 1GB, files larger than that should be split automatically.

Any help would be appreciated. My skills in batch are close to none-existent. Python would work fine for me! EDIT: Or even better, a full fleshed-out application that does the job!

Comment: Why not write it in Python?

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant by "Python would work fine for me" - but the problems around the webdav / filesystem stuff as well as the other problems aren't easy to solve for me, not even with Python. I could need some help there.

Comment: There is a backup tool I love, `borg` (or `borgbackup`). While it cannot natively support `webdav`, you could do a local then periodic upload / mirror.  The deduplication part would likely save you a ton of both space and necessary bandwidth. As this isn't a direct answer per se, I thought I'd post it as a comment.  Borg URL: https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but in case it helps others, I wrote a small Python script to solve almost exactly this problem. It won't solve problem 4 -- I'm not sure what behavior would make sense there (if a new file is created that matches one of the segments of a previously split file, what should it do?), but otherwise I wrote it to do precisely what you're saying -- backup local files to a cloud provider.

At any rate, it's probably a good starting point that you could add the file splitting functionality to if you wanted. It's available here:

https://github.com/j4m3z0r/davsync

I've only tested it against a couple of WebDAV servers, and they all seem to have a slightly different interpretation of the protocol. Let me know if you find it doesn't work for you and I'll try to get it fixed.